# MySql query that will count the amount of 'C' based on distinct 'A'

Tags: mysql, count, aggregate-functions

I need a MySql query that will count the amount of 'DomainName' hosted by each distinct 'HostAuthority'.

Given this table:

```
HostAuthority  HostName           DomainName
-----------------------------------------------------
one.com        ns01.one.com       seasonsbysidselz.dk
one.com        ns02.one.com       seasonsbysidselz.dk
one.com        ns01.one.com       seasons52.dk
one.com        ns02.one.com       seasons52.dk
mono.net       ns1.mono.net       seasons4you.dk
mono.net       ns2.mono.net       seasons4you.dk
one.com        ns01.one.com       seasons4all.dk
one.com        ns02.one.com       seasons4all.dk
unoeuro.com    ns1.unoeuro.com    seasons.dk
unoeuro.com    ns2.unoeuro.com    seasons.dk
unoeuro.com    ns3.unoeuro.com    seasons.dk
```

How can I select this?

```
HostAuthority   HostedDomains
-----------------------------
one.com         3
mono.net        1
unoeuro.com     1
```

Comment: Use [`GROUP BY` and aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `COUNT(DISTINCT something)` in SQL, as follows:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d2ed6/1/0

```
select HostAuthority,
       COUNT(DISTINCT DomainName) As HostedDomain
  from tbl
 GROUP BY HostAuthority
```

Pretty cool, huh?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this query:

```
SELECT HostAuthority,COUNT(DISTINCT DomainName) AS HostedDomains FROM nameservermap GROUP BY HostAuthority ORDER BY HostedDomains DESC;
```

Thank you Ollie! Didn't know about COUNT(DISTINCT ... Very cool indeed :)